# SQL query Limit with only for one field

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have SQL table called `Table 01`, and it has 3 columns as `X`, `Y` , `Z`

What i need to restrict the `SELECT SQL` query to only return the `Z` column data when request for `X & Y`

Is there are way of restricting the SQL `SELECT query` ??

Comment: i can have both MySQL or Oracle

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Please edit your question adding some sample data and desired result. Also, post what you tried so far and the issues with your code

Comment: i need to setup restriction only to select Z, the requester should not able to get the result for SELECT * query

Comment: You want to forbid, for example, `select x, y, z` and allow `select z`, did I understand well?

Comment: yes spot on, that's exactly i want

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a table in schema `USER1` and you want to allow another user, say `USER2`, to only query for column `z`; you can build a view on your table and only give the grants on the view, without giving any grant on the table; in this way `USER2` will only see the columns included in the view, and not the whole table.

For example

**USER1**:

```
create table completeTable(x number, y number, z number);
create view restrictedTable as select z from completeTable;
insert into completeTable values (1, 2, 3);
grant select on restrictedTable to USER2;
create public synonym restrictedTable for restrictedTable;
```

**USER2**:

```
SQL> select x, y, z from completeTable;
select x, y, z from completeTable
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select x, y, z from restrictedTable;
select x, y, z from restrictedTable
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "Y": invalid identifier


SQL> select z from restrictedTable;

         Z
----------
         3
```

Comment: But i need to get the result (Z) from a where clause of X and Y, how can i do that,

e.g
SELECT Z from <table> where X='1' AND Y='2'

Comment: You say you want to "see" a column to apply a filter, but you don't want to "see" it to get the values? I believe you can't

Answer (score 1):

this is for MySQL

You need to build a stored procedure with `x` and `y` as parameters which returns the `select z from t0`, and then play with user privileges to deny access to select x,y from t0 and grant execute of procedure:

```
CREATE USER 'ReadOnlyUseruser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '' ;
GRANT SELECT (z) ON MySchema.t0 TO 'ReadOnlyUseruser'@'localhost' ;
GRANT EXECUTE ON MySchema.* TO 'ReadOnlyUseruser'@'localhost';

select x,y from t0

Error Code: 1143. SELECT command denied to user 'ReadOnlyUseruser'@'localhost' for column 'x' in table 't0'
```

but `select z from t0` will work
now, for the filter part:

```
DELIMITER $$

drop procedure `sp_t0`;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@'localhost' PROCEDURE `sp_t0`(
    in px int,
    in py int   
)
 BEGIN   
    SELECT z FROM t0
    where x=px and y=py;
END
```

finally, after login with ReadOnlyUser

```
SET @x = 23;
SET @y = 35;
call sp_t0(@x,@y);
```

this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict the SELECT query for Z

```
SELECT X, Y
FROM 
   Table01
```

If you restrict the SELECT query for x, y

```
SELECT Z
FROM 
   Table01
```

Comment: no i need to setup restriction only to select Z, the requester should not able to get the result for SELECT * query

Comment: i have updated my answer. it restriction to select Z and requester can't able to see this column

Comment: if this query not solved you problem. please provide some demo table data and your accepted data.